# Convert File from UTF16 LE to UTF16 BE

Tags: endianness, utf-16le

There is a question from an old test that is confusing me:
"When converting a file from UTF16-LE to UTF16-BE will the file be smaller or bigger afterwards?"

I thought it's just a different order of the bytes, but I dont understand why it should change the file's size?

Comment: So? The answer is 'neither'.

Comment: I'd say the same, but somehow the anser is "smaller", so I'm not sure

Comment: I suppose that in some cases some tool might remove a BOM. Otherwise, I'd say that it was a broken test.